# Bad commit is not letting me revert, undo or discard files

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I have a bad commit which is not allowing me to change or commit to my repository and I'm not sure what it is. Someone in my group updated this wrong and now this stuff is happening.

[image]

I don't know how to fix this, those files don't even exist in my repository. I never created them, or even placed them anywhere. Can someone help me figure this out? The last time it happened I just got rid of the repository and created a new one. I'd prefer not to do that again, it is extremely annoying.

Comment: I don't see a commit but unstaged deletions. Are you trying to get rid of those "files to commit"?

Comment: Yeah I want them gone, but every time I try to discard them it says they're in use. They're not, they don't even exist in my computer. I don't know why I'm getting this error, these files don't even exist within the repository.

Comment: I see, are you familiar with the git console?

Comment: If you mean the Git Shell, yes, I've used it with windows before and with Ubuntu as well. I assume they work the same way? Never deleted any files though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allright then, first make sure you commit all other existing work except from those files you want gone. Confirm those files are there with `git status`

Fire up the Git Shell, navigate to the repo directory from it and then type the following

```
git add -A
git stash
```

Run `git status` again to confirm if they are gone.

Comment: Glad that did it for you